# Error issues when using Cut Fill operation in ArcGis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-conversion, error-010067

I wonder if someone is able to assist with an issue I have about a series of errors I get when using the *cut/fill* tool in spatial analyst, ArcGis 10.2? Someone posted a question sometime last year entitled:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58460/what-is-causing-arcmap-errors-010302-010067-while-using-3d-analyst-cutfill

but as you can see it was closed for being too localized. This, however, is my exact problem, and I have seen that the page has been viewed many times, so I don't think I am the only one! The author of the question said that a miraculous solution to the problem manifested itself the following day; I have not been so lucky. Does someone know of a solution to this?

Comment: A quick review of that original question makes me believe that you will be best to simply start yours by saying that you believe it may be the same problem but that you are going to re-work the problem more thoroughly in order to try to find and record a solution.  The original question looks like it needed a bit more work before it could be systematically answered, and that only a "miracle" saved that user from doing the groundwork of getting the problem into a reproducible procedure.